# Mobile devices web browser simulator

Tags: mobile, browser

I'm looking for iPhone, iPad, Android and other mobile and smartphones web browsers simulators on x86. I would like to check how my web application written for standard web browser will be displayed on these devices.

Answer (score 1):

The dev kits for these platforms include platform emulators, in which you can run the browser for that platform and load your web site to see how it will look.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html
http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/develop.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm programming a web application for mobile and I use JQueryMobile.

You can have more informations here :

http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to quickly view how a webpage would render at various mobile device resolutions then `synthphone.com` is a nice little webpage...

http://synthphone.com

you can even link directly to a url via query strings. for example, here is one that should load the Sencha Touch 2 carousel. Use your mouse like a finger to slide around the images etc.

http://www.synthphone.com/?u=http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/carousel/index.html

have fun!